# Eager Loading parent with Ancestry gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading, ancestry

Simples Question.

I'm using `ancestry` gem to make a model acts as a tree. I wanto to create the following json response:

```
regions: [{name: "Name", parent_name: "Parent Name"}, ...]
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Region <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry

  def parent_name
    parent ? parent.name : ""
  end
end
```

How can I eager load the parent, so I can render the json with the parent name?

Comment: may be add a default scope?

Comment: This would have to be done in the Region.where section, could you add that to your question?

Comment: I've gone with the awesome nested set gem. Right now I don't have a specific query, I would like just to take all regions and get the parent name to be loaded within it.